Inequality for Gaussian measures
Let $\mu$ denote a centered Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$, $K=(-\infty, a] \times \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$ ($a\ge 0$) and $L=\mathbb{R}\times C$ where $C$ is a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^{k-1}$, symmetric around the origin. Do we have
$$\mu(K\cap L)\ge \mu(K) \mu(L) \;?$$
Note the following:

The Gaussian correlation inequality does not apply because $K$ is not symmetric around the origin.
There are some results for nonsymmetric sets but I have not found a paper that would cover this case.
Some numerical work suggests that it works when $k=2$.


Does not it reduce to Gaussian correlation inequality for the sets $L$ and $K_1:=[-a,a]\times \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$ using symmetry?

This is very possible, but I simply do not see how.

Denote $K_0=[-a,a]\times \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$, $K_{-}=[-\infty,-a]\times \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$, $K_{+}=[a,\infty]\times \mathbb{R}^{k-1}=-K_-$.
We have $$\mu(L)(\mu(K_0)+2\mu(K_+))=\mu(L)=\mu(L\cap K_0)+\mu(L\cap K_-)+\mu(L\cap K_+)
\\=\mu(L\cap K_0)+2\mu(L\cap K_+)\\\geqslant \mu(L)\mu(K_0)+2\mu(L\cap K_+)$$ by Gaussian correlation equality (and symmetry of $\mu$). Thus $\mu(L)\mu(K_+)\geqslant \mu(L\cap K_+)$, and $\mu(L)-\mu(L)\mu(K_+)\leqslant \mu(L)-\mu(L\cap K_+)$ that is equivalent to $\mu(L)\mu(K)\leqslant \mu(L\cap K)$.

Thank you very much!
